# How do I sort a list by value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, list, sorting

I want to sort a list from high value to low value. Its output value comes from voting in a poll.

here is the code that creates the list:

```
function votingScore($item, $itemvoted) {
$hector=count($itemvoted);$totalvotes=0;$in=0;$stepstr='';
$totalvotes=SumArray($itemvoted);
$in=0;
if ($totalvotes==0) { $totalvotes=0.0001; }
while ($in<$hector) {
    $stepstr=$stepstr.'<li>'.stripslashes($item[$in]).(int)(($itemvoted[$in]/$totalvotes)*100).'% ';
    $stepstr=$stepstr.'</li>';
    $in++;
}
return '<ul>'.$stepstr.'</ul>'; }
```

The votes are saved in a text file that lokes like this:
optionOne:11:optionTwo:5:

I tried doing the following:

```
arsort($stepstr);
foreach ($stepstr as $key => $val) {
echo "stepstr[" . $key . "] = " . $val . "\n"; }
```

**FIX:**

```
function votingScore($item, $itemvoted) {
    $combineSort = array_multisort($itemvoted, SORT_DESC, $item, SORT_DESC); //added this line and got it to work
    $hector=count($itemvoted);$totalvotes=0;$in=0;$stepstr='';
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/array.sorting.php

Comment: @jan1337z come on! I bet this function is responsible for showing some important... Stuff. Whatever is the Stuff. It is surely something important, I guess. It should be, possibly. Maybe not? I don't know.

Comment: @jan1337z better like this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly you just need to call `arsort` on `$itemvoted`  such as:

```
function votingScore($item, $itemvoted) {
    $success = arsort($itemvoted);  //Success will either be True or False 
    ....
```

However, depending on what `$itemvoted` looks like (is it associative or not) you may want a different sorting function as stated by @George_Cummins.  See the [link](http://php.net/manual/array.sorting.php):

Comment: Thanks @ajon! This does some part of the job. The weird thing is that it only sorts the numbers in the list and not the option that belongs to the value.  
  
When the values are like this:  
optionOne:12  
optionTwo:18  
optionThree:13  
  
it is sorted like this:  
optionOne:18  
optionTwo:13  
optionThree:12  
  
but I want it to be like this:  
optionTwo:18  
optionThree:13  
optionOne:12

Comment: ok, see edit... you need to use arsort which will sort the array in reverse order keeping the indicies the same.  That assumes $itemvoted is an associated array mapping values to options: e.g. {[12]=>optionOne,[18]=>optionTwo,...}

Comment: Figured it out! I used the following:
     $combineSort = array_multisort($itemvoted, SORT_DESC, $item, SORT_DESC);